# Creating system service in android

Tags: android, android-source

I tried implementing a custom HAL, API and system service with this link https://github.com/nayobix/add-new-hardware-hal-android-5-lollipop
(Also checked few others)

I followed every instruction and code and made the system.img.

I am using Android 5.1.1 source to build the system image.

But the device doesnt boot up when I checked the logcat in Android Studio. I found the system service is not loading.

```
08-09 11:32:27.123 160-160/? I/DEBUG: Abort message: 'art/runtime/jni_internal.cc:769] JNI FatalError called: Native registration unable to find class 'com/android/server/ZigbeeService'; aborting...'
08-09 11:32:27.123 160-160/? I/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000174bd  /system/lib/libandroid_servers.so (JNI_OnLoad+172)
08-09 11:32:27.336 20208-20208/? E/Zygote: Exit zygote because system server (20435) has terminated
```

Also while compiling, I got some warning like.

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: Did you try build the whole source from scratch? @Jaffin MK

Comment: Thank you for responding. yes I did, I did 'make update-api' and then 'make -j8' to compile and build the system.img file

Comment: I am getting the feeling. I did everything right with the code but the trouble is in compiling the source. The warnings that I got. Some error in java compiling??

Comment: I would recommend first compile the whole source, Because you might use API that that change not just the 'system.img' and try to flash it all to the device without your code and then with your code.

Comment: Oops you were right. The source is not getting compiled even without my code. It is those warnings. I had compiled one or two days back and it was working I am not sure if Ubuntu made some updates and broke the build environment.

Comment: Check java version have not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Had to start from scratch, rebuilding and compiling the entire source.

The github was little incorrect. Actually I had to create another folder to put the service java class file. Which is why android couldnt find it (as per the debug message).

Happens when you follow someone elses work blindly. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as correct so it's easy to see when visiting this page.

Comment: I am new using the site. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @jcxmej Can you please provide tutorial what you done because i am new in this and want to implement same...

Answer (score 0):

The code in that project is for 5.0.1 (Lollipop), where you are building for 5.1.1 (also Lollipop, but different).  Be sure that the core framework, HAL, etc. files were just patched with the changes from this repo into your AOSP rather than copied over.  If you simply copied over the files from this repo, you likely wiped out something which was added to system server or other framework components in between 5.0.1 and 5.1.1.  You will most likely need to manually examine and patch the files.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have not copy pasted any file from the link. I inserted the relevant code from the link and modified the existing files. And created the new files where ever necessary. What ever existed before remains as such. I have only added few things to it. But I am unsure if I added in the wrong folder or wrong file. But I cross checked with other links which tells me the same.

Comment: Also can you advise what are those warnings while compiling the source. IF that might be reason behind all this mess?

Comment: Those warnings are pretty normal when building AOSP, they should not be anything you'll need to worry about.  When you grabbed AOSP, are you sure you grabbed 5.1.1 from a release tag and not the `master` branch?  The `master` branch is generally considered unstable.  To @JaffinMK's point above, you may wish to start by building the stock AOSP first and verify your base build is good before adding in patches / changes.